# Using `execute immediate bulk collect into` with dynamic queries in Pro*C

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to do a bulk collect of a dynamic query under Pro*C, but I haven't been able to find any single example on the Internet about that. For example, for a simple query like `select level, level + 100 from dual connect by level <= 100`, I guess I should do something like:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    char proc_query[LARGE_ENOUGH_QUERY_BUFFER_SZ];

    TYPE sample_tbl_t IS TABLE OF number(10);
    sample_tbl_t level;
    sample_tbl_t level_100;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

char const example_query[] = "select level, level + 100 from dual connect by level <= 100";
memcpy(proc_query, example_query, sizeof(example_query));

EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :proc_query BULK COLLECT INTO :level, :level_100;
```

... or something like that, but I don't know how to use the contents of `level` and `level_100`, how to know the number of rows returned and such. I have tried to search information about it but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Pro*C, but - in PL/SQL - that would be something like:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    TYPE sample_tbl_t IS TABLE OF number(10);
  3    lvl     sample_tbl_t;
  4    lvl_100 sample_tbl_t;
  5  begin
  6    execute immediate 'select level, level + 100
  7                       from dual
  8                       connect by level <= 100' bulk collect into lvl, lvl_100;
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line('lvl    count = '|| lvl.count);
 11    dbms_output.put_line('lvl100 count = '|| lvl_100.count);
 12  end;
 13  /
lvl    count = 100
lvl100 count = 100

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Besides, your declaration section is wrong. Compare it to my example.

Also, you probably shouldn't name variables `level`, it can mislead the reader (looks like pseudocolumn in hierarchical queries).